# How to execute nifi dataflow from the command line

Tags: apache-nifi

I have prepared a dataflow in nifi. Is there a way to execute that from the command line.?

Thank you,
Srujana

Comment: Can you describe more about how you mean it to work?  Are you trying to deploy a template from the command line?

Comment: Hi James. Yes i want to deploy template from the command line. When i checked in the resources, came to know that nifi command line is not yet ready. But, just curious if there is any other way

Answer (score 4):

I believe Matthew Burgess has built a [NiFi API client in Groovy](https://github.com/mattyb149/nifi-client) that will deploy and run a NiFi template, as [described in this email thread](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/nifi-users/201601.mbox/browser).